# jest testing for react + redux saying undefined value in prop

Tags: reactjs, redux, jestjs

I'm testing a program made with React and Redux in Jest and I'm getting this error in the console.

```
console.error
  Warning: Failed prop type: The prop `prop` is marked as required in `Component`, but its value is `undefined`.
```

This is the code I wrote for the test:

```
import React from 'react';
import { Provider } from 'react-redux';
import renderer from 'react-test-renderer';
import configureStore from 'redux-mock-store';
import App from './App';
 
const mockStore = configureStore([]);
 
describe('My Connected React-Redux Component', () => {
  let store;
  let component;
 
  beforeEach(() => {
      store = mockStore({
      prop: [],
      hasErrored: false,
      isLoading: false,
    });
    component = renderer.create(
      <Provider store={store}>
        <App />
      </Provider>
    );
  });
 
  it('should render with given state from Redux store', () => {
    expect(component.toJSON()).toMatchSnapshot();
  });
```

This is what App.js looks like (the provider is added on index.js)

```
import Component from './components/Component';

function App() {

  return (
    <div className="App">
        <Component></Component>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Comment: Can you post the code for App?

Comment: It's been updated!

Comment: Does `Component` have something like `mapStateToProps`?

Comment: Yes it does. Component.propTypes = {
 fetchData: PropTypes.func.isRequired,
    items: PropTypes.array.isRequired,
    hasErrored: PropTypes.bool.isRequired,
    isLoading: PropTypes.bool.isRequired
};
const mapStateToProps = (state) => {
    return {
        items: state.items,
        hasErrored: state.itemsHasErrored,
        isLoading: state.itemsIsLoading
    };
};

const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch) => {
    return {
  fetchData: (url) => dispatch(itemsFetchData(url)),
    };
};

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `App` component renders a `Component` component. It is `Component` that is complaining that it requires a prop. You should update `mapStateToProps` to provides the `prop`, or you can simply just do:

```
import Component from './components/Component';

function App() {

  return (
    <div className="App">
        <Component prop="foo"></Component>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```